# Input type "number", add another option (exception) or custom input type

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a webservice that there are some forms with some inputs. 99% of the inputs will be numbers but in some cases it may be needed to add an X in there. I currently have them at `<input type="number+>` but is there any way i can customize this so that it will make like an exception for certain chars? like X.

I'm more concerned for tablet/phone views and how easy it will be for the user to input those values. I was hoping i wouldn't have to go `<input type="text">`

Thank you